# Does Snowpack support importing files using a glob pattern?

Tags: glob, snowpack

I am trying import all the files matching a glob pattern using [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/):

```
import allFiles from '../static/posts/**/*.md';
```

In Rollup you can achieve it with [rollup-plugin-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-glob), is there anything like that in [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) ecosystem?

Answer (score 2):

Snowpack has just released support for glob importing in 3.2.1! The syntax mirrors [Vite's glob import support](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import), so code like…

```
const modules = import.meta.glob('./dir/*.js')
```

would be transformed into the following:

```
const modules = {
  './dir/foo.js': () => import('./dir/foo.js'),
  './dir/bar.js': () => import('./dir/bar.js')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) doesn't support importing multiple files matching a glob pattern, but there is [an open issue to implement this feature](https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/issues/1165), so I guess this will eventually be supported.